# Wondering how much space would I need for reinstalling Windows on my PC?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, virtual-machine

I'm planning to reinstall my OS on my computer - upgrading and putting a new SSD drive (as c drive) and installing on it Windows 7 ultimate x64 (and than mt current 1TB drive would become designated just for my D partition for data).

**Now, this is the problem** : as I'm planning to practice at home  networknig/MCSA stuff and installing Windows Server as VM and more  - in that case, **would a 128GB SSD be enough for my (new) C drive or better it be 240/250GB ?**

I'm not planning to install  other source heavy SW like games or graphic SW etc., just the regular basic stuff (Office, AV and so on), so probably the whole VM environment is gonna be the heavy and important one. Guess it's gonna be at least one MS server and some desktops, virtual router...all as VM machines for learning and practicing MCSA stuff as said.

I'll be happy to hear an answer from others - MCSA students, anybody ?

Comment: 128 is minimal, I would go 240.

Comment: Until the first major Windows update, 128 GB might work... then  applications and the whole Windows folder are copied to Windows.old, using gobs of disk space. In particular, the Windows\WinSxS folder may have more than 7 GB, and it is replicated.

Answer (score 1):

Many SSD actually have faster write speeds with larger size, especially in the low end 64/128gb.

Since you are using VM's on your setup and the larger is faster reason I would go with the 240/256gb ssd.

> How much space does it take to install windows?

Roughly 40gb.

I have run Windows 10 computers with 80gb hdd, but they only have office and the 3 browsers on them.

Windows often uses temp files, and the winsxs folder tends to grow over time.  This eventually becomes a hassle as you have to run disk clean up on a regular basis.

I have used 120/128 for windows OS, but I end up having to install all my software on another ssd.  Even then some software still writes files to the c: drive.

I have many more PC with 240gb hdd, and never run out of space.  Now depending on how many VM's you need you might still have problems.  However, I doubt it.